# How can I avoid a postback message?

Tags: asp.net, postback

I am relatively new in programming and I have a doubt about postback. I searched in some pages, but I couldn't solve my question.

I created a web page and I use postback in it that updates some informations in the page. That works without any problems. However, after the postback is fired, if the user presses F5, a message appears asking to confirm the form re-submit.

Why exactly this message appears and how can I avoid it?
If the user would press F5, I want the page reload, without any alerts.

I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear enough, but I really don't understand postback how much I'd like.. =)

Comment: Are you able to submit the page without any problem ?

Comment: You mean after postback? I don't need to submit the page after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought in the following code to solve my problem, using a javascript event:

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 116) {
        location.href = 'pedidos.aspx';
        return false;
    }
});
```

It solves my problem, because I avoid the postback message as I want and the page is reloaded. 
But is this a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

By Default ,

The **method** is **post** means it will confirm while reloading the page.

The **method** is **get** means it wont ask anything.

Why this happens,Whenever the post method called severe action gonna happen in server,so it just confirms from the user.There is no need in the case of get Method.

I hope u are clear with this solution.

Comment: But is there a way to avoid this message, using postback? How can I do it?

Comment: @ Everton According to me,Its no way to avoid that.I recommend you to manually submit the data through ajax or hidden form submission using javascript.

Comment: But I'm not submitting the data, I just want to avoid this message when the user presses F5. What do you say about my solution below?

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid your issue is to place a hidden field on the page.  When the form is submitted, check the hidden field.  If no value, process the form, and populate the hidden field with a value.  If it has a value, then do nothing.

I prefer using an on-click event on a button, instead of using the postback event.

As to why it happens, a refresh sends a request along with the form data back to the server causing another postback.

Comment: I used a postback because I have a html link, if I had a button, I'd use an on-click event too. I posted a solution that I thought, which do you think is better: yours or mine?

Answer (score 0):

This is known as page re-submission.

When you refresh the browser, it will resend the last request you did. If it was a POST request (like you do in case of postback) then it will re-post the information but before doing it you'll see the warning message you describe.

To prevent this:

```
Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
```

Which changes the response to a GET instead of a POST. Prevents the 'Form Resubmission' dialog.

Comment: I think I understood what you said, but I'm not sure in what place I should put this code..